# How to draw a line from one corner of a div to one corner of main screen with HTML and CSS and keeping it responsive?

Tags: html, css, drawing

I want to use only HTML and CSS and want to draw a line between corners of a centered div to the corners of main screen area like picture below, the main thing is that how to keep it responsive.

[image]

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/draw-diagonal-line-using-css/#:~:text=In%20CSS%2C%20we%20have%20used,values%20as%20%E2%80%9C40%25%E2%80%9D. this might help you to draw diagonal lines and for login box just use `position :absolute` for the login box and `position :relative` for the parent `div` and set the distance from top and left with `top` and `left` CSS properties please note use % for `top` and `left` due to responsiveness...`position` helps you to put your box on top of your diagonal lines.

Comment: so amyn ways, what have you tried? Pseudo-elements? SVG?

Answer (score 0):

//HTML

```
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 500px;
    border: 3px solid red;" class="parent">
    <div class="diagonal-ltor" style="border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(0, 47, 255);    
    transform-origin: left top;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 500px;">
    <div class=" diagonal-rtol" style="border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(0, 47, 255);    
    transform-origin: left top;"></div>
   </div>
   <script src="sample.js"></script>
```

sample.js

```
 let parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
 let lineLToR = document.querySelector(".diagonal-ltor");
 let lineRToL = document.querySelector(".diagonal-rtol")
 let lineSize = (Math.sqrt(parent.clientWidth ** 2 + parent.clientHeight ** 2) / 
 parent.clientWidth) * 100 + .7;
 let rotateRadian = Math.asin(parent.clientHeight / 
 (Math.sqrt(parent.clientWidth ** 
 2 + parent.clientHeight ** 2)));
 let rotateDegree = rotateRadian * (180 / Math.PI);

 lineLToR.style.width = `${lineSize}%`;
 lineLToR.style.transform = `rotate(${rotateDegree}deg)`;
 lineRToL.style.width = `${lineSize}%`;
 lineRToL.style.transform = `rotate(-${rotateDegree}deg)`;
```

this can draw you diagonal lines which is responsive, for adding your login box use position as I mentioned above.